# Extensible log aggregation compatible with Elasticsearch (like logstash)

Tags: windows, linux, logs, log-analysis, parser

Trying to find some alternatives to logstash for log parsing/aggregation.

- It needs to handle multiple text log file formats.
- It needs to be extensible (probably with regex) to handle new formats
- It should be able to output to Elasticsearch (HTTP & JSON)
- It should work on Windows and multiple Unix types (particulary Ubuntu/Red Hat linux)
- Free/Open Source greatly preferred - but if compelling, paid would be acceptable

What meets these critera, and how do they compare as far as complexity and memory/processor usage?